# Weka, j48 tree (Number of Leaves : 1 Size of the tree : 1)

Tags: r, weka

I am new to this Weka. I have this csv file I would like to play around in weka, so I converted it into a arff file by using R. After I loaded the arff file into the weka and try to use j48 on it in classifier, the result return

Number of Leaves  :     1

Size of the tree :  1

which is rather odd to me. I should be seeing a tree instead. This is not the first time I bumped into this 1 tree 1 leaf problem, it happened to my some other data sets as well. Any chance anyone know what could cause this, maybe I need to preprocess the data set in certain way? Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Can you post your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,

Try changing the parameter of the algorithm to unpruned, it works for me

cheers